# How to superimpose two ggplots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 2 `ggplots` generated by below codes

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggdist)
set.seed(1)

DF1 = rbind(data.frame('Label' = 'A', val = rnorm(200, 5)), data.frame('Label' = 'B', val = rnorm(500, 10)))
DF2 = rbind(data.frame('Label' = 'A', val = rt(200, 2)), data.frame('Label' = 'B', val = rt(700, 3)))

Plot1 = ggplot(DF1, aes(x = Label, y = val, fill = 'red'))  + stat_dotsinterval(position = 'dodge')
Plot2 = ggplot(DF2, aes(x = Label, y = val, fill = 'green')) + stat_dotsinterval(position = 'dodge')

Plot1
Plot2
```

Those are individual plots, however I want to combine them into just one `ggplot` with appropriate legend.

Is there any way to do this for above case?

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `library(patchwork); Plot1 + Plot2 + plot_layout(guides="collect")`

Comment: Thanks. But I wanted to have 2 plots in same plot layout as if they are `superimposed`. I do not want to create 2 layout windows

Comment: In that case you'll probably want to combine your data into a single data frame. Something like this: `library(tidyverse); list(DF1=DF1, DF2=DF2) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id="data.source") %>% ggplot(aes(x=Label, y=val, colour=data.source, fill=data.source)) +
  stat_dotsinterval(position="dodge")`

Comment: Many thanks. Instead of `4` vertical histograms, can I have `2` verticals? One for Label `A` and another for Label `B`? Along the first vertical line, I would have 2 plots for `DF1` and `DF2` but only for `A` and similarly for `B`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to `eipi10`'s comment:

```
library(dplyr); library(ggplot2)
bind_rows(DF1, DF2, .id = "src") %>% 
  mutate(name = if_else(src == "1", "red", "green")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Label, y=val, colour=name, fill=name)) +   
  stat_dotsinterval() +
  scale_color_identity(aesthetics = c("fill", "color"), guide = "legend") +
  theme(legend.position = "top")
```

[image]

Comment: That is just prefect. Can I add legend in above plot for `red` and `green`?

Comment: please see edit